# Creating my first Custom Template in django

Tags: html, django, templates

I am building my first app in Django 1.8 with Python 2.7, I need to pass some value from the view.py to my HTML template.

I am using the following code

in Views.py

```
import datetime
from django import template
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

register = template.Library()

class CurrentTimeNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, format_string):
        self.format_string = str(format_string)

    def render(self, context):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        print "Render in CurrentTimeNode:", now
        return now.strftime(self.format_string)

@register.simple_tag
def current_time(format_string):
    print "Current Time"
    return CurrentTimeNode(datetime.datetime.now().strftime(format_string))

current_time = register.tag(current_time)


def post(request):
    datos = "hola"
    print datos

    return render_to_response('sitio/post.html', { 'datos':datos} , RequestContext(request))
```

In Post.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        some title
    </head>
    <body>
            {% current_time %}
            {{ timezone }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Where I want to get the time using the tag "current_time" and dump in my html file. I am getting the following message error:

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:
Invalid block tag: 'current_time'

[image: I the block tag is not recognized]

What is missing to register the Block Tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be nice if you can properly format your code (I can't edit your post for some reason). Judging by your post though, the issue is that you are not loading the tag. You should put the current_time function in a folder called "templatetags" (this folder should be at the same level as your views.py and models.py file). Add the

```
__init__.py
```

file to ensure the directory is treated as a Python package.

Next, in the templatetags folder, place current_time function in a file called current_time.py. Then in your template, add this line to the top of the template:

```
{% load current_time %}
```

Look at the documentation here for more information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback it was perfect, I have a lot to learn. How to format as well as lot of small tricks about the use of this environment. So far going well

Comment: @JorgeZavala Great, goodluck with the learning. You can mark this question as answered if my response correctly addressed your issue.